# Kafka consumer offset commit inside completable future

Tags: java, multithreading, java-8, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a Kafka consumer instance created inside a thread as part of constructor and within the thread inside run method I do call different web services and to keep the call non blocking I am using completable future. My issue is that I am not able to issue commit by calling thenApply method and passing Kafka consumer instance because it gives me an error that Kafka consumer is not thread safe. Though inside my commit method I have made the code

```
synchronized(consumer) {
  commitResponse();
}
```

still i get `ConcurrentModificationException`.

```
class KafkaConsumerThread implements Runnable {

  KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer;

  public KafkaConsumerThread(Properties properties) {
    consumer = new KafkaConsumer<String, String>(properties);    
    ...
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    try {
      // synchronized (consumer) {
      consumer.subscribe(topics);
      while (true) {
        if (closed.get()) {
          consumer.close();
        }
        ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(120000);
        for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {
          getAsyncClient().prepareGet(webServiceUrl)
              .execute()
              .toCompletableFuture()
              .thenApply(resp -> callAnotherService1(resp))
              .thenApply(resp -> callAnotherService2(resp))
              .thenApply(resp -> commitResponse(resp, consumer));
          }
        }
      }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      ...
    }
```

In the above code I get exception inside the commitResponse method that "KafkaConsumer is not safe for multi-threaded access". Though inside my commit response if I enclose the commit inside synchronized(consumer) I still get the error.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably it's because `poll` method is not synchronized, and is executed (while still running holding internal kafka lock), while your async GETs do the commit.

See references to private methods:
`org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.acquire()`
and
`org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.release()`
in `org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer`